# phpqrcode changing qr code color

Tags: php, qr-code

I am trying to generate a different colored QR Code using phpqrcode library.

My code sample is below:

```
<?php
    include('./phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
    $uri=$_GET['uri'];
    $backColor = 0xFFFFFF;
    $foreColor = 0x000066;
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    QRcode::png($uri, false, QR_ECLEVEL_L, 6, 1, false, $backColor, $foreColor);
?>
```

However, the colors just seem to get ignored and the QR code always comes out as black on white.

I am pretty sure I am using the latest version of the library (v1.1.4):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/files/releases/

Anyone managed to get this working?

Comment: Where are you getting the assumption that it accepts colours? The method is defined as [`public static function png($text, $outfile = false, $level = QR_ECLEVEL_L, $size = 3, $margin = 4, $saveandprint=false)`](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/docs/html/class_q_rcode.html#a1b90c0989105afa06b6e1c718a454fb5). You might be able to change `$col[0] = ImageColorAllocate($base_image,255,255,255); $col[1] = ImageColorAllocate($base_image,0,0,0);` around like 987 to get the colors you want.

Comment: h2ooooooo, I found this article which seems to indicate you can change the color of the QR code: http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-qr-codes-in-php/. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: h2ooooooo, I tried changing those values in phpqrcode.php but to no avail.  However, you have pointed out my stupidity below. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [sourceforge version](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/docs/html/class_q_rcode.html#a1b90c0989105afa06b6e1c718a454fb5) of the method looks like the following:

```
static QRcode::png  (
    $text,
    $outfile = false,
    $level = QR_ECLEVEL_L,
    $size = 3,
    $margin = 4,
    $saveandprint = false 
)
```

and does not include any colours. You seem to be looking for the [**GitHub version instead**](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode), that [defines the method](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode/blob/master/phpqrcode.php#L3117-L3121) as the following:

```
public static function png(
    $text, 
    $outfile = false, 
    $level = QR_ECLEVEL_L, 
    $size = 3, 
    $margin = 4, 
    $saveandprint=false, 
    $back_color = 0xFFFFFF, 
    $fore_color = 0x000000
) {
```

(*Psst, the article you read also mentions it: "Start by downloading the latest PHP QR Code library **from GitHub**", and it also includes a link to the [GitHub project](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode)*)

Answer (score 6):

In the `qrimage.php` file try to change `$col[0]` and `$col[1]` values and see the difference, good luck.